# symfony db and doctrine user structure

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a site with 2 types of users: searchers and workers.

My firewall is on all the site and both of the types are from the the same provider (same table in DB).

The problem is that there is one entity for them -> site_users, and the diff is by a column on a db that decides their role.

But searcher has another one to many variable,
and the worker has an other one to many variable.

I cant define them in the main class because than they will infect the other user as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and it's not a problem.

I simply add to the parent entity -> User

2 varibales: searcher & employer

each of them is one to one relationship with User

If I want to fetch them I simply call the one needed,
they dont interrupt each other.